# Regex to select all text between inner quotes in case of nested quotes

Tags: java, regex

I wanted to select text within quotes using regex as per below scenario -

Regex should select text between the quotes. If there are nested quotes it should select all inner nested quotes instead of outer ones.

Ex 1 - 
`Sample.text.value "The quick brown fox"`

Result should be - **The quick brown fox**

Ex 2 - 
`Sample.text.value "The quick brown fox" random text here one "jumps over the lazy dog" random text here two`

Result should be - **The quick brown fox** and **jumps over the lazy dog**

Ex 3 - 
`"Sample.text.value "The quick brown fox" random text here one "jumps over the lazy dog" random text here two"`

Result should be - **The quick brown fox** and **jumps over the lazy dog**

I am trying this regex `"([^"]*)"`

This works fine in first two cases. 
But in third case it does not select as expected.

It selects **Sample.text.value** and **random text here one** and **random text here two**.

But I need **The quick brown fox** and **jumps over the lazy dog** to be selected.

Is it possible via regex ?

Comment: Which programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: @blhsing I am using Java.

Comment: are you looking for: `(?<=")\S[^"]+\S(?=")`?

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks. It helped to extract the part I wanted.

Comment: did this regex work?

Comment: @Onyambu Yes It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next regex `(?m)(?!^)\"((?:(?!\").)*)\"`.

To try the regular expression online and get an explanation, click [here](https://regex101.com/r/M8iZGa/2).